# What is the difference between the title() method and wm_title() method in the Tkinter class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am using Python 2.7 and I wanted to know if there was a difference between the title() method and the wm_title() method for the Tkinter class. The following code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("My App")
root.mainloop()
```

and

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("My App")
root.mainloop()
```

accomplishes the same thing. Is there something hidden that is going on?

Comment: It is one function with two names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same thing really. `wm` methods are used to communicate with the window manager. Hence `wm` for window manager.

Wm class is used as a mixin by the root `tk.Tk()` window. You can access setting the title as you have by `title` or `wm_title` and other window manager attributes.

You can see the documentation [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm)